# How to turn js string in something similiar to AST tree?

Tags: javascript, tokenize, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to turn string expression that looks something like this:

```
"SALARY('@JohnSmith') = {USER.workingHours} * {USER.hourlyRate}"
```

into something similar to AST. For example:

```
const result = [
  {type: 'function', name: 'SALARY', params: ['@JohnSmith']},
  {type: 'entity', name: 'USER', fields: ['workingHours']},
  {type: 'mathOperation', operator: 'mutliply'},
  {type: 'entity', name: 'USER', fields: ['hourlyRate']} 
]
```

I need some advice on library, that is capable to:

1. Perform some tokenization based on my custom rules
2. Povide custom callback function for every entity based on my rules

something like:

```
tokenizer.register(someValiedRegexp, async callback(name, param) => ...)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's called a "parser". There are many libraries available for this.

Comment: babel is fairly popular for doing this https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-generator#usage

Answer (score 0):

mmoo.js can do this job. All i need is to set rules for tokenization